# i want looping answer and question its not like what i want

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-4

i have quiz app but after i submit the answer is not like i want. my answer still looping the questions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pRST.png)

controller quiz

```
public function hasilKuis()
  {
    $check = $this->kuisModel->find('id_quiz');
    $data = [
      'title'   => 'Hasil Kuis',
      'hasil'   => $this->kuisModel->findAll(),
      'checks'  => $this->request->getVar($check)
    ];
    
    return view('user/kuis/hasil', $data);
  }
```

view result quiz

```
<?php $score = 0; ?>
            <?php $i  =  1; ?>
            <?php foreach($hasil as $s) : ?>
            <?php foreach($checks as $checked) : ?>

            <div class="soal mb-3">

              <p><?= $i++; ?>. <?= $s['pertanyaan']; ?></p>
              <?php if ($checked != $s['jawaban']) : ?>


              <div class="form-check" style="background-color: palevioletred;">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDisabled" id="flexRadioCheckedDisabled"
                  value="<?= $checked ?>" disabled>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioCheckedDisabled">
                  <?= $checked ?>
                </label>
              </div>


              <div class="form-check" style="background-color: aquamarine;">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDisabled" id="flexRadioDisabled" disabled>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDisabled">
                  <?= $s['jawaban']; ?>
                </label>
              </div>


              <?php else : ?>


              <div class="form-check" style="background-color: aquamarine;">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDisabled" id="flexRadioCheckedDisabled"
                  value="<?= $s['jawaban'] ?>" disabled>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioCheckedDisabled">
                  <?= $s['jawaban']; ?>
                </label>
              </div>


              <?php $score = $score + 1 ?>

              <?php endif ?>


            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

please help me how to fix this looping. can anyone help me how to do this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the picture show how it is now, or how you wanted it? It wasn't really clear. And whichever it is, we need to see a picture showing the opposite case as well, so we can understand the difference.

Comment: @ADyson the picture is what is happening now and i dont want it

Comment: Well then you need to explain exactly what you _do_ want, please. We are not mind readers unfortunately. It would also be helpful if we had some sample data from your database to work with.